Parent page redirect to child page using htaccess
I am using wordpress, I have to redirect the parent page to the child page. I have tried the below code but it's not redirecting.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webinar/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /business/ [L,R=301]

I have checked the above code in the htaccess checker. The below is the screenshot


What is full URL of parent page that you want to redirect to and what is new child page URL?

@anubhava, parent url https://example.com/webinar and child url https://example.com/webinar/business

ok in that  case try this rule just below RewriteEngine On line: RewriteRule ^/?(webinar)/?$ /$1/business [L,NC,R=301]

Reason: ^/webinar/$ will not match /webinar due to the trailing slash that is expected by the matching pattern. The question marks in ^/?(webinar)/?$  make those slashes optional. The first question mark allows for an absolute path (which you have to match against in a RewriteCond (that is documented) as opposed to a RewriteRule where you need to match a relative path, so without leading slash. The second question mark allows for a trailing slash but does not enforce it.
